# Is there an advantage in running a local private node?

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, testnets, mix

Reading the excellent write up about [Where can I learn how to develop DApps using the solidity programming language](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2414/54)
I wondered if using Mix with scenarios only versus deploying a contract in a private local node had some significant differences?

Apart from using geth on the local node to interact with the contract I don't see any but I'm not familiar enough to be sure.

From a DApp development point of view why would one choose one or another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real benefit of Mix is that you can:

- debugging assembly code / source code (breakpoint, local variable, state variable, ...)
- use the integrated web browser to develop/test the front end (or use your own web developer tool for that).
- check the gas cost for each executed code (at a statement level). You may want to use that to develop cheaper contract.
- you can use scenario to test your contract
- you can also deploy contract

(the two last points are not a specificity of mix)