# Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is there an easy to access list of Solidity / Smart Contracts / Dapps source code examples?

Related information:

- [Is there a list of DAPPS that are already useable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-there-a-list-of-dapps-that-are-already-useable)
- [Where can I learn how to develop DApps using the solidity programming language?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/where-can-i-learn-how-to-develop-dapps-using-the-solidity-programming-language)

Comment: [List questions are generally off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/226837) and [here is some more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11780/226837).

Comment: This list question seemed good enough to convert to a community wiki.

Comment: check https://github.com/bellaj/smart-contract

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Please Edit Me** to help keep this an up-to-date easily accessible resource. This is a community wiki post.

---

## Documentation & Introduction

#### Solidity Documentation

- Website: http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

#### Solidity Baby Steps

From [euri10](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/54/euri10) below.

- Code: https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps

---

## DAOs

#### The DAO

- Code: https://github.com/slockit/DAO
- Website: https://daohub.org/index.html

---

## BTC Relay

#### BTC Relay

- Code: https://github.com/ethereum/btcrelay
- Website: http://btcrelay.org/

---

## Ethereum Wallet (Mist) Multisig Contract

#### Ethereum Wallet (Mist) Multisig Contract

From [How to verify Mist's standard multisig wallet using Etherscan tool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/how-to-verify-mists-standard-multisig-wallet-using-etherscan-tool) and [Documentation On Multisig Wallet in Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/867/documentation-on-multisig-wallet-in-mist).

- Code: https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol

---

## Proof Of Existence

#### NoterEth

NoterEth, pronounced "Notaryth", is a prototype notary and "Proof of Existence" DAPP. By submitting hashes of documents you can proof on a later date that you were privileged to certain information at a point in history. The transfer of documents can enable other contracts to allow certain access based on who owns a hash.

- Code: https://github.com/maran/notareth
- Website: Download a copy of the code and run it from your computer.

---

## Libraries & Utilities

#### Random Number Generators

- Code: [alexvandesande/Random generator](https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/259b4ffb581493ec0a1c)
- See also [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

#### Ethereum Date And Time Tools

Working prototype.

- Code: https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime

#### StringUtils #1

From [decypha](https://www.reddit.com/user/decypha) in the [reddit/r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4f3lbt/solidity_stringutils_library/) post.

Basic string utilities for Solidity, optimized for low gas usage.

- Code: https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils

#### StringUtils #2

By `@pipermerriam` from [How can I modify bytes32 result to uint?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-can-i-modify-bytes32-result-to-uint) by `@euri10`.

- Code: https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-string-utils

#### Ethereum Alarm Clock

Schedule calls to Ethereum contracts.

- Code: http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/source/v0.7.0/
- Website: http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/

---

## Tokens & Currencies

#### The Good Old Greeter

- Website: https://www.ethereum.org/greeter
- Step by step guide to deploying and running Greeter: [Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private) .

#### Token

Create your own crypto-currency.

- Code: https://www.ethereum.org/token

#### The Great Unicorn Meat Grinder

Grind up your [Unicorn Tokens](https://ethereum.org/donate) into <strike>dogfood</strike> meat.

- Code: https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/3abc9f741471e08a6356
- Website: https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/eca0b87da89ab28fa50c

#### Community Currency

A work-in-progress.

- Code: https://github.com/segovro/Community-Currency

---

## Exchange

#### Etheropt

A decentralised options exchange.

- Code: https://github.com/etheropt/etheropt.github.io
- Website: http://etheropt.github.io/

#### EtherEx

A decentralised exchange - alpha.

- Code: https://github.com/etherex/etherex
- Website: https://etherex.org/

#### Customizable Atomic Swap Contract

Posted by reddit user [David_Moskowitz](https://www.reddit.com/user/David_Moskowitz) on [Customizable Atomic Swap Contract (DGD for Ether)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4iecu7/customizable_atomic_swap_contract_dgd_for_ether/).

- Code: https://github.com/gaurangtorvekar/DGD-Swap-Contract/blob/master/DGD_Swap.sol
- Description: https://medium.com/@attores/using-the-dgd-swap-contract-from-attores-6631490d4334#.a060s73f1

---

## Gambling

#### Ether Dice

A place where you can throw away your ethers.

- Code: https://etherdice.io/#contract
- Website: https://etherdice.io/ (unavailable at the moment)

#### Ethereum Dice (or Simple Dice Game)

Another place where you can throw away your ethers.

- Code: https://etherscan.io/address/0x78b058ccda93816487c655367dcb79664a216ad2#code
- Announced at https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1428982.0 . No website. Just send your ethers to the contract address.

#### Sleth - Ethereum Slot Machine

Working prototype.

- Code: https://github.com/jorisbontje/sleth

#### EtherPot

You can't smoke this. It's a provably fair Lottery.

- Code: http://etherpot.github.io/
- Website: http://etherpot.github.io/

---

## Pyramid Schemes

#### GovernMental

As posted by reddit user [ethererik](https://www.reddit.com/user/ethererik) on [GovernMental's 1100 ETH jackpot payout is stuck because it uses too much gas](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4ghzhv/governmentals_1100_eth_jackpot_payout_is_stuck/) , the payout for this pyramid scheme may be stuck because the payout code requires the array of past creditors and amounts to be cleared, and this operation costs too much gas. The code to clear internal storage is:

```
creditorAddresses = new address[](0);
creditorAmounts = new uint[](0);
```

Apparently 1100 ethers are stuck in limbo.

**WARNING** - This is a situation Smart Contract developers need to be aware of!

The question [How to clear large arrays without blowing the gas limit?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/how-to-clear-large-arrays-without-blowing-the-gas-limit) has one answer to work around this issue. Thanks `@Nick Johnson`.

- Code: https://etherchain.org/account/0xF45717552f12Ef7cb65e95476F217Ea008167Ae3#code
- Website: http://governmental.github.io/GovernMental/

#### Ethereum Pyramid

A Pyramid scheme.

- Code: https://ethereumpyramid.com/contract.html
- Website: https://ethereumpyramid.com/

#### King Of The Ether Throne

Become a King or Queen, get rich and immortalise your name.

- Code: https://github.com/kieranelby/KingOfTheEtherThrone/blob/v0.4.0/contracts/KingOfTheEtherThrone.sol
- Website: http://www.kingoftheether.com/ . The author detected a problem with this code and a draft post-mortem investigation can be found at http://www.kingoftheether.com/postmortem.html .

#### The Greed Pit

- Code: https://etherscan.io/address/0x446D1696a5527018453cdA3d67aa4C2cd189b9f6#code
- Website: http://thegreedpit.com/

#### Ethereum Doubler

Double your ether. Ponzi.

- Code: https://etherchain.org/account/0xfd2487cc0e5dce97f08be1bc8ef1dce8d5988b4d#code
- Website: http://app.etherdoubler.com/

#### Protect The Castle

Another Ponzi game.

- Code: https://etherchain.org/account/0x7D56485e026D5D3881F778E99969D2b1F90c50aF#code
- Website: http://protect-the-castle.ether-contract.org/

---

## Messages

#### Etherboard

An image powered by the blockchain.

- Code: http://etherboard.io/contract
- Website: http://etherboard.io/

#### Ethereum Wall

A decentralised and open public message board.

- Code: http://ethereumwall.com/tech.html
- Website: http://ethereumwall.com/

#### Decentralised Twitter

Working prototype.

- Code: https://github.com/yep/eth-tweet
- Website: http://ethertweet.net/

---

## Not Categorised Yet

#### Meteor Dapp Wallet

Multi-sig, daily-limited account proxy/wallet - "The Ξthereum wallet. NOTE The wallet is not yet official released, can contain severe bugs!"

- Code: https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet

#### Maker

Maker is a Decentralized Autonomous Organization that creates and insures the dai stablecoin on the Ethereum blockchain.

There are several public dapps and libraries in the Maker ecosystem:

- https://github.com/makerdao/maker-user
- https://github.com/makerdao/maker-otc
- https://github.com/makerdao/maker-darts
- https://github.com/nexusdev/feedbase

Higher level information about Maker can be found here:

- Code: https://github.com/MakerDAO
- Website: https://makerdao.com/

#### EtherId

Register a domain name for your Ethereum account.

- Code: https://github.com/lexansoft/EtherID.org
- Website: http://etherid.org/

#### Public Votes

A publicly verifiable Voting System - working prototype.

- Code: https://github.com/domschiener/publicvotes
- Website: http://publicvotes.org/

#### State of the Dapps

- You will have to trawl around to find the good ones - http://dapps.ethercasts.com/ .

#### SafeMarket

From [aakilfernandes](https://www.reddit.com/user/aakilfernandes) in the [reddit/r/ethdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/4es16x/where_can_i_find_some_solidity_smart_contract/) post - "Check out dapps.ethercast.com and look in repos, then search for .sol or .se files. Got a couple dozen here if you'd like to take a look."

- https://github.com/SafeMarket/dapp/tree/master/app/contracts

#### Oraclize

From [bertani](https://www.reddit.com/user/bertani) in the [reddit/r/ethdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/4es16x/where_can_i_find_some_solidity_smart_contract/) post - "Here you can find some Oraclize-based ones ;)".

- Code: https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity
- Docs: http://docs.oraclize.it/

#### ether.camp

From [inasacu](https://www.reddit.com/user/inasacu) in the [reddit/r/ethdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/4es16x/where_can_i_find_some_solidity_smart_contract/) post - "Try ether.camp".

- Web page with Smart Contract source code: https://live.ether.camp/contracts

Comment: This will be a hell to maintain. Why don't you create a list of actual smart contracts including source code?

Comment: I was hoping that by being a community wiki post, this will get updated by the community.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin has some Solidity code such as wallet, scrypt, and library.  This is where Christian Reitwiessner (Solidity author), Gavin Wood, and Vitalik Buterin, have placed some of their DApps.  Overall worth exploring, though some may not have a UI, or maybe written in Serpent.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**DappSys**

dappsys is contract system framework. It is a collection of Solidity contracts (classes) to help manage multi-contract dapps on ethereum.

**Audit**

On February 24th, 2016, Piper Merriam completed and signed a code audit covering the state of Dappsys as of commit 4dceee5.

**Installation**

`npm install dapple
dapple install https://github.com/nexusdev/dappsys`

**Github**

https://github.com/nexusdev/dappsys

Comment: Lazy question, are these contracts on the main network already for reuse?

Comment: They are, you can find the addresses (for morden testnet and main network) in the dappfile at https://github.com/nexusdev/dappsys/blob/master/dappfile

Answer (score 5):

I loved [those baby steps](https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/tree/master/contracts) when I got interested in Solidity. Some practical simple stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can check the full list of 
smart contracts people publishing 
today on the live network.

Most of them are really interesting 
study cases.

https://live.ether.camp/contracts