# What are GavCoins and what is their significance?

Tags: dapps, history

Quite simply, what are [GavCoins](http://www.ethport.com/alubbe/GavCoin) and what is their significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GavCoin is a sample smart contract implementation of a token in the very early days of the Ethereum blockchain. It's significance is that token is implemented in **LLL** developed about 2 years ago.

(In my opinion, LLL was too hard to work with. Just use the new Solidity programming language - you can find examples at [Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/where-can-i-find-some-solidity-smart-contract-source-code-examples)).

From [Ether Fund - Currency GavCoin](http://ether.fund/contract/75a44/currency-gavcoin), GavCoin is a:

> Simple currency contract in LLL, aka GavCoin, by Gavin Wood.

And LLL is:

> #### LLL
>
> Lisp Like Language (LLL) is a low level language similar to Assembly. It is meant to be very simple and minimalistic; essentially just a tiny wrapper over coding in EVM directly.

More information on LLL can be found at [LLL PoC 6](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/wiki/LLL-PoC-6/04fae9e627ac84d771faddcf60098ad09230ab58).

Answer (score 6):

GavCoin was an example coin contract created by Gavin Wood. It serves as a:

- Demonstration of how to create an independent token using Ethereum
- [Joke](http://gavwood.com/gavcoin.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is pretty good example 
of GavCoin with source attached
and internal state full analysis

https://live.ether.camp/account/b4abc1bfc403a7b82c777420c81269858a4b8aa4