# How to know, inside the contract function, the amount of gas that will be refunded in the end

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, gas-refund, gas-estimate

Consider the following situation: my function can be divided into 2 parts

1. Always consumes constant gas;
2. Always results in a refund of `0 < R < 1500000` gas.

After the second part had happened, but before the end of a function call, how do I know the value of `R`?

The problem is that the `msg.gas`(which is remaining gas) doesn't account for the refund(cause the refund cannot be used inside the transaction itself). Due to this the following approach will fail:

```
uint startGas = msg.gas;                   // e.g. 100000 gas
delete myArray;                            // consumes 40000 gas, but will refund 20000 in the end
uint gasUsed = startGas - msg.gas + 21500; // gasUsed = 100000 - 60000 + 21500 == 61500 gas (21500 is for initial tx and function call)
```

We estimated that the gas spent for execution will be `61500`, but in fact, after the refund, transaction receipt gasUsed value will be `41500`.

I wonder if there is something like `msg.refundGas` is planned, or should I create a feature request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to know the value of the EVM's refund counter from inside the EVM; if you want to account for refunds, you'll have to do them yourself, manually.

Answer (score 3):

Given that `delete myArray` can be dangerous ([How to clear large arrays without blowing the gas limit?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3373/42)), you probably want to know exactly how much storage you are clearing.  Then you could multiply the number of storage slots cleared by [15,000 and check if the refund needs to be limited.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/859/42)  Precise gas calculations can be tricky and could require testing.

Feel free and anyone can submit feature requests on Github.

Comment: `delete myArray` is just an example of an operation that results in a gas refund. In my real cases, there is lots of different logic that may, or not, result in a refund.

Comment: Nick said it well, currently "There's no way to know the value of the EVM's refund counter from inside the EVM".  Seems like a reasonable feature request to propose.

Comment: Can we simulate the contract outside the blockchain with current input values and retrieve the simulated amount of gas used into the smart contract? (Note this is a newbee question as I don't even know if you can get data from outside the blockchain in a contract...)

Comment: @NMassart Simulation can be done, but you're correct that contracts can't retrieve data.