# How to provide gas value when we can't calculate it, when using arrays?

Tags: solidity, remix, out-of-gas, arrays, gas-estimate

Recently, I am trying arrays(search) in browser-solidity and I found that the number of items in it causes changes in the gas consumption.

For making a call we need to specify the gas amount but it depends on the items count in the array.

Is there a workaround to handle these kinds of operations in Ethereum?

Answer (score 2):

A *workaround* is to provide more gas than might be needed, for example 10-50% more gas, because unused gas will be refunded.

It's also important to **design contracts so that their gas usage is bounded**.  When using arrays and iterating, it's important that if the array keeps growing without limit, that you only iterate over a fixed number of items per transaction.  A function's interface could look like `iterate(startingIndex, numberOfItems)` and each transaction would pass the next `startingIndex`.

Solidity docs on [Gas Limit and Loops:](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#gas-limit-and-loops)

> Loops that do not have a fixed number of iterations, for example,
>   loops that depend on storage values, have to be used carefully: Due to
>   the block gas limit, transactions can only consume a certain amount of
>   gas. Either explicitly or just due to normal operation, the number of
>   iterations in a loop can grow beyond the block gas limit which can
>   cause the complete contract to be stalled at a certain point.

Do not iterate over the whole array in a single loop, because it could exceed the block gas limit, and permanently block the remaining part of the contract from executing. For a real world example see [How to clear large arrays without blowing the gas limit?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/how-to-clear-large-arrays-without-blowing-the-gas-limit)