# Hidden problems in "set array to empty array to clear it" approach

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays, memory

I needed a way to clear a storage array in my contract. I've seen [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/how-to-clear-large-arrays-without-blowing-the-gas-limit) answer, but I tried to think of different approach (My arrays are most probably will contain enormous amount of elements) and have come up to this.

I create empty storage array of the same type, as the array I want to clear. Then I just assign empty array to filled array. Here is contract I used for testing.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
    address[] array;
    address[] helper;

    function Test() public {
        array.push(0x0);
        array.push(0x0);
        array.push(0x0);
        array.push(0x0);
    }

    function getSize() public view returns (uint256) {
        return array.length;
    }

    function clear() public {
        array = helper;
    } 
}
```

It works as intended, `getSize()` returns 0 after I call `clear()`.

So now I wonder, if there are some hidden problems in this approach, including something like "dangling pointers" or increased gas cost.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [docs about types](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#delete) thoroughly, I found that calling `delete` on dynamic array frees all allocated memory.

> `delete a` assigns the initial value for the type to `a`. I.e. for integers it is equivalent to `a = 0`, but it can also be used on arrays, where it assigns a **dynamic array of length zero** or a static array of the same length with all elements reset.

Internally, calling `delete` on array assigns it to a new empty array, like I did.

> It is important to note that `delete a` really **behaves like an assignment to** `a`, i.e. it stores a new object in `a`.

Transaction cost is lower for `delete` call, than for manual assignment to empty array (not speaking about storing this empty array in storage memory). In my example, deleting an array of 1000 addresses by calling `delete` cost *5060808* gas; deleting the same array by manual assignment cost *5270025* gas.