# function in smart contract to allow owner to burn all the tokens

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20

I have tried this:

```
function burn(uint256 tokens) public returns(bool){
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= tokens);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokens);
    Burn(msg.sender, tokens);
}
```

but this code will only burn the tokens by the address owner. I want the contract owner to be able to burn all the tokens and making totalSupply to be 0.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen in the previous answers, if your token is distributed to tens of thousand of holders, it becomes impractical and almost impossible to set all their balances to 0.

You can achieve the same thing by:

1. set the `_totalSupply` to 0
2. create a boolean variable called `allBurned` and set it to `true` in the `burnA()` function
3. modify all the functions that manage funds and put `require(!allBurned)` (or more complex code that does what you want)

Comment: You start by saying that this is not possible then you show a half-baked solution. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with a typical erc20 implementation. If you really wanted to burn everything, you'd have to keep an array of all addresses that have a non-zero balance, and loop through that array in `burn` to set them all to zero.

Comment: Yes I agree that's not feasible to implement it in erc20, but that was just a use case I was trying ti implement to check the concept of how to implement it, thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty the `balances` array and set `_totalSupply` to `0`.
To empty the array have a look at: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3377/31933

Another story is what kind of event you should trigger. I guess you should fire:

```
Burn(msg.sender, _totalSupply);
```

(although you can't use the value of `_totalSupply` as it's already zeroed, so store the value temporary in some other variable before zeroing)

Comment: Balances isn't an array, it's a map.

Answer (score 0):

To burn all of the tokens at once you would need to iterate over all elements in balances, which is not possible without modifications to the code, but even with those modifications, a transaction like that would very quickly be larger than the block gas limit when the token is used by a couple thousand addresses.

Here is a way to do it, I would not recommend doing that though:

```
mapping (address => uint) accountBalances;
mapping (uint => address) accountIndex;

uint accountCount;
function burnAllTokens()
{
    for(uint i=0;i<accountCount;i++)
    {
        accountBalances[accountIndex[i]] = 0;
        _totalSupply = 0;
    }
}
```

You obviously need to store all of the accounts in `accountIndex` whenever someone send to them.

Comment: @Grunzwanling, that worked, thanks for the help mate!