# How can I modify bytes32 result to uint?

Tags: bytes32

I want to separate three last digits of the most recent block header hash and get the result as uint.

I can get the answer as bytes32 by this code, but how can I change this result to uint?

```
contract test
{
    bytes32 lastblockhashused;
    uint lastblocknumberused;

    function test()
    {
        lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1)  ;               
        lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused);
    }

    function getTest1() constant returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 number1 =lastblockhashused;
        return number1 & 0xfff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or just do away with your `number1` variable completely, while also remembering to change the return type:

```
function getTest1() constant returns (uint) {
        return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this in sol version 0.5.12 and it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply cast a bytes32 to uint with `uint(number1)`.

Comment: I have additional question related to this http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/why-cant-i-pass-this-functions-value-to-variable

Comment: Not anymore as of solidity ^0.5.0

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg how are we supose to do this conversion on 0.5.0 ++ ?

Comment: @JoãoQuintanilha I don't know .. but there must be a soluton here somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

you can use @pipermerriam excellent library : [ethereum-string-utils](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-string-utils)
 with the function

```
function bytesToUInt(uint v) constant returns (uint ret)
```

It does exacxtly what you want.

It's usable as a library copying the .sol or using contract calls against via `0xcca8353a18e7ab7b3d094ee1f9ddc91bdf2ca6a4`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.