# Why can't I pass this function's value to a variable?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

This question is related to question

[How can I modify bytes32 result to uint?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-can-i-modify-bytes-32-result-to-uint)

I'm trying to pass result to variable AA, but AA's value is always 0. Function getTest1 shows the right answer, but I can't pass that answer to variable AA.

```
contract Test {
    bytes32 lastblockhashused;
    uint lastblocknumberused;
    uint AA;

    function test() {
        lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1)  ;               
        lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused);
    }

    function getTest1() constant returns (uint) {
        return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff;
    }

    function Test2() {
        AA=(uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff);
        return; 
    }

    function getTest2AA() constant returns (uint) {
        return AA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to make sure your question's formatted properly, rather than relying on friendly strangers to do so.

Comment: This works just fine for me in Browser Solidity, if I call `Test2()` first. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you for help. In the future, I will format questions properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

The reason why your original example does not work is because:

- The class is named `class Test` (with an uppercase `T`).
- Your constructor function is named `function test()` (with a lowercase `t`), and will not be treated as the class constructor by the Solidity compiler.
- The function `function test()`, not being the class constructor, does not get called when this contract is inserted into the blockchain, and the values of `lastblocknumberused` and `lastblockhashused` are initialised to the values of `0` and `"0x0000...0000"` respectively.
- When calling the function `Test2()`, AA is calculated from the `"0x0000...0000"` value of `lastblockhashused`, and the result is `0`.

---

### The Non-Working Version

Here's the original code where the constructor `function test()` has a different name from the class `class Test`. The member variables have been made public to trace the problem.

This example does **NOT** work as expected.

```
contract Test {
    bytes32 public lastblockhashused;
    uint public lastblocknumberused;
    uint public AA;

    function test() {
        lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1)  ;               
        lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused);
    }

    function getTest1() constant returns (uint) {
        return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff;
    }

    function Test2() {
        AA=(uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff);
        return; 
    }

    function getTest2AA() constant returns (uint) {
        return AA;
    }
}
```

Here's what I executed:

```
var testSource='contract Test { bytes32 public lastblockhashused; uint public lastblocknumberused; uint public AA; function test() { lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1) ;  lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused); } function getTest1() constant returns (uint) { return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff;  } function Test2() { AA=(uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff); return;  } function getTest2AA() constant returns (uint) { return AA; }}'

var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);

var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition);
var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.Test.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
```

Waited for:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0x75774a4837e268ea63ba5544160c9a56f96da558
```

Confirming that the call to the constructor `test()` **DID NOT RUN** :

```
> test.lastblocknumberused()
0
> test.lastblockhashused()
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> test.AA()
0
```

---

### The Working Version

Here is the modified code where the constructor `function Test()` has the exact same name as the class name `class Test`. The member variables have been made public to trace the problem. This example works as expected:

```
contract Test {
    bytes32 public lastblockhashused;
    uint public lastblocknumberused;
    uint public AA;

    function Test() {
        lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1)  ;               
        lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused);
    }

    function getTest1() constant returns (uint) {
        return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff;
    }

    function Test2() {
        AA = (uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff);
    }

    function getTest2AA() constant returns (uint) {
        return AA;
    }
}
```

Here is what I executed:

```
> var testSource='contract Test { bytes32 public lastblockhashused; uint public lastblocknumberused; uint public AA; function Test() { lastblocknumberused = (block.number-1) ;  lastblockhashused = block.blockhash(lastblocknumberused); AA = 1; } function getTest1() constant returns (uint) { return uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff; } function Test2() { AA = (uint(lastblockhashused) & 0xfff); } function getTest2AA() constant returns (uint) { return AA; }}'

> var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);

> var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition);
var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.Test.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
        if (!e) {
            if(!contract.address) {
              console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
```

Waited for:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0x307001bf417b42433e0c8d08ef73f08a3dd874c6
```

Confirming that the call to the constructor `Test()` ran :

```
> test.lastblocknumberused()
9875
> test.lastblockhashused()
"0x20de2b012e7f7fe9fbce0d87a2b2565c8152e91106ed22306eb5318b394ad8dd"
> test.AA()
1
```

Ran `Test2()`:

```
> test.Test2(eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: testCompiled.Test.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
"0x76fcaf7784ea002cf4b89e65b016c5954e9fa3f0baf1a40f1782e775eb481667"

> test.lastblocknumberused()
9875
> test.lastblockhashused()
"0x20de2b012e7f7fe9fbce0d87a2b2565c8152e91106ed22306eb5318b394ad8dd"
> test.AA()
2269
```

Comment: I did not understand, that I have to run both functions.

Comment: Your version of the code did not work because of a mismatch in the constructor function name.