# How to convert bytes32 to uint8 in solidity ^0.5.0?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, bytes, type-casting

I can see that conversions from bytes to uint used to be much [easier](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-can-i-modify-bytes32-result-to-uint) in previous versions of solidity. Now, using the same syntax, I get this error:

> TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "uint8"

I know about Piper Merriam's [library](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-string-utils), but I wouldn't add so much code just for a small type conversion. Isn't there a more elegant way?

Using solidity 0.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it ever was because `bytes` is a dynamic array of `byte` which means it has a `length`. Is it possible you saw `bytes32` conversion to `unit`? That is totally acceptable in that both are 32-byte words.

This compiles under 0.4.25 as well 0.5.2.

```
contract Bytes {

    function convert(bytes32 b) public pure returns(uint) {
        return uint(b);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this conversion is trouble in all cases I'm aware of.

```
contract Bytes {

    function convert(bytes b) public pure returns(uint) {
        return uint(b);
    }
}
```

*In my opinion*, conversion of `bytes` and `string` to numbers, string manipulation, etc. are problematic issues that should *usually* be dealt with by software clients rather than burdening contracts with such concerns. It's a case where the contract team should strongly resist overloading the contract with concerns that software clients are capable of resolving.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed, it was a `bytes32` to `uint8` conversion that I saw. Interesting, so now in solidity ^0.5 you can do `uint(b)` but you can't do `uint8(b)`. I guess `uint8(uint(b))` would do the trick, but I'm wondering if there's any place where this is documented? I couldn't find anything in the solidity docs for 0.5.2

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. TBH, I'm not sure about the state of the docs for this.